# Old Lazy loaded images is not changes when new images is replaced in the Image Url Android?

Tags: android, caching, lazy-loading

Hi am using [thest1 lazyload github](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) .i have loaded all images asynchronously,All goes fine ,but my problem is when i have changes any image in server.In the lazy loading  images is not showing its new images only old images that loaded earlier is begin shown.**For example** I have image data of 4 persons profile picture which is shown in the listview when i first load the screen ,when one of the user changed his/her profile picture , even after the image is changed by the user it is not showing in the listview ,it loaded the old image only,How do i displays the new picture.(AS WE SEE IN WHATZ APP).Can Any one suggest any help,or snippet .I have Also Tryed **universal image loader**,it is also loading the old image only.

Thank you

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: if i clear caches ,new images will display.but how would i know when to clear the cache?if i clear cache each time its make lagging.

Comment: you could some info like 1 or 0 form server. depending on the value clear the cache. 1 means update. 0 means no changes

Comment: Im using lazy method too , u should clear cache to get image.
or u can set flag inside app and check what image should be cleared from cache if it changedin other side.

Comment: can u plaese  explain  as an answer @Andrey

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for retrive image :

```
String myxml = SaxXmlParser.getXmlFromUrl(targetCtx
                    .getString(R.string.imgurl)

            SaxXmlParser parser = new SaxXmlParser(xml, "Imagelist");
            parser.runParser();
                for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : parser.getParsedData()) {
                TableImage images = new TableImage();
                images.url = hashMap.get("imageurl");
                                images.new = Integer.parseInt(hashMap.get("new"));
```

and in ur code check if "new" flag is "1 or 0"

if "1" :

```
private File cacheDir;
public File getFile(String url){
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;

}

public void clear(String url){
    File files= url;
    if(files==null)
        return;
    for(File f:files)
        f.delete();
}
```

edit for getting online file size :

```
URL url = new URL("http://hayoola.com/myimage.png");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

if size is different from the one on cache , delete image on cache folder.

Comment: but i will no change any data in my link for example the link i am call is https://www.ramz.com/userid.png even after he/she change the image it will be the same image url.an one more thing is that in ios when images is change it automatically changed.but in android it does not why?

Comment: ok if u dont want to get that code from other side , then u can get 
each image size with "File.length()" from cached imaged and comapre it to downloaded image from url . if equal then nothing to do , else 
replace the cached one with new one.